# What is the correct way to get an Entity with it's navigation property in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

How I get an Entity with it's navigation property in Entity Framework Core? I have seen in `docs.microsoft` that I have to use `.Include()` and it's working in a project but this time it's not working.

## Model.cs

```
public class UniversityModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LongDescription { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public List<UniSession> Sessions { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<UniEmail> Emails { get; set; }
    public List<UniPhone> Phones { get; set; }
    
}
```

And I'm accessing the UniversityModel with it's navigation property like.

```
UniversityModel university = await _context.Universities
    .Include(u => u.Phones)
    .Include(u => u.Emails)
    .Include(u => u.Sessions)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.ID == id);
```

It's getting the `university`  correctly but Navigation properties are not including.
For make it clear look at the `Model` below all the navigation property models are same with foreign key of university.

```
public class UniEmail
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int UniversityId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

What is the wrong how correctly I can Include all the navigation properties and If my Including code is wrong then how it's worked in another project?

Comment: I am unsure if this will fix your problem, nor am I sure that is even required in EFCore, but I always make my navigation properties `virtual`. Can you give that a try? (i.e. `public virtual List<UniEmail> Emails { get; set; }`

Comment: @ nbokmans still not working, can you see any wrong in my code or model?

Comment: Can you try adding the reverse navigation property? For example add `[ForeignKey("UniversityId")] public virtual UniversityModel University { get; set; }` to `UniEmail`

Comment: Make sure the ID field in `UniveristyModel` is has attribute `[Key]` aswell. Also another wild guess would be that `ID` is name sensitive, meaning you named the primary key column in `UniversityModel` `ID` but in your `UniEmail` you are trying to look for a foreign key `UniversityId` (lowercase `d`, change to `public int UniversityID`).

Comment: you got the point.. all the problem was `ForeignKey` the `ForeignKey` should be `UniveristyModelID`.. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your entity model does not follow EF Core conventions and you don't use fluent configuration. Although EF discovers the relationship through collection navigation property, since there is no inverse reference navigation property and `UniversityId` field is not identified as FK, EF maps FK to a [shadow property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) called `UniversityModelId`.

EF Core FK naming conventions are explained in the [Fully Defined Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#fully-defined-relationships) section of the documentation:

> If the dependent entity contains a property named <primary key property name>, <navigation property name><primary key property name>, or <principal entity name><primary key property name> then it will be configured as the foreign key.

In other words, `UniversityId` will be considered conventionally as FK if:

(1) `UniversityModel` class is called `University`
(2) `ID` property of `UniversityModel` class is called `UniversityID` (and tagged with `[Key]` attribute because it would not match the PK convention)
(3) You add inverse navigation property called `University`:

```
public UniversityModel University { get; set; }
public int UniversityId { get; set; }
```

And of course it can be mapped explicitly with fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UniversityModel>()
    .HasMany(e => e.Emails) // with collection navigation property
    .WithOne() // and no reference navigation property
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.UniversityId); // and foreign key
```